# TypeScript Transform find named function and insert code outside

Tags: typescript

I am looking to write a simple TypeScript transform that takes this:

`const MyVariableName = targetFunctionName(...)`

and converts it to

`const MyVariableName = targetFunctionName(...)
MyVariableName.displayName = 'MyVariableName'`

I have written a basic babel plugin before where the "Babel Plugin Handbook" was super useful when working with the AST. But I'm having trouble finding something similar for TypeScript Transforms which makes it difficult to grasp the structure of a transform.

The list below is the 3 steps I know I need to do:

1. Look for targetFunction
2. Grab node.parent.name
3. Insert code below (this is where I am having issues) in format `${node.parent.name}.displayName = '${node.parent.name}'`

I am looking for good resources, hopefully something similar to Babel's handbook. Or some guidance on how to do step 3. Because I am pretty sure that I have step 1 and 2 figured out.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I thought I'd provide some insight.

At the base level is something called a Block (or SourceFile which behaves a lot like a Block), which you can recreate with ts.createBlock providing a list of statements. If I detect a block I use ts.visitNodeChildren recursively to see if targetFunctionName is within that block (if one of the children is another Block I go back to step 1 to avoid adding code in the wrong scope).

Then once you know the function is in the block you're in you can recreate the block with the original statements and an added statement.

Typescript has a bunch of handy and straightforward ts.create functions (make sure you include the compiler to get autocompletion) for all of the things you'd need to do, to find out what you need to do and which nodes to create I use https://astexplorer.net/ (select javascript as a language and typescript as a compiler) and type in your desired result statement.

I believe the process for adding to a sourceFile is similar-ish to adding to a block, but more complicated. I get around this by only expression of interest and putting it in a new block, so:

```
const MyVariableName = targetFunctionName(...)
```

becomes:

```
{
    const MyVariableName = targetFunctionName(...)
    MyVariableName.displayName = 'MyVariableName'
}
```

bypassing the whole issue of recreating blocks or sourcefiles. It's however more messy, and will cause the let keyword to not function correctly (for my use case it has other benefits so that's why I decided to do it this way).